# Django загрузка картинок в статик приложения

Tags: django, изображения

Если есть известное приложение "блог", то вроде бы кажется логичным пихать картинки не куда-нибудь, а в /blog/static/images/blog/ (это правда?). И вот что надо сделать, чтобы картинки загружались туда, а не просто в /images/news/?

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/blog/", null=True)
```

Comment: Это не кажется логичным. Статика для статичных данных. Загружаемые изображения должны быть "напиханы" в MEDIA_ROOT и быть доступны по MEDIA_URL соответственно.

Comment: Скорее запиханы. Даже несмотря на то, что они используются только данным приложением?

Comment: Да, в static должно быть только то, что добавлено туда на этапе разработки и может измениться только в процессе разработки новой версии.